# Empty objects using app.post and AngularJS + mongoose on node.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

My REST API is posting empty objects.

I am getting the value from **req.body.name**

If I log it **console.log(req.body.name);** I get the value on my console.

```
POST: 
{ name: 'typing any name', status: null }
typing any name
```

So the workflow between my frontend (**angular.js**), the form and the backend (**node.js, express, mongoose**) seems to work. Now I POST the value, but I get an empty object in my mongoDB.

**{"_id":"543a50a974de6e2606bd8478","__v":0}**

```
app.post('/api/offers', function (req, res){
var offer;
console.log("POST: ");
console.log(req.body);
console.log(req.body.name);
offer = new OfferModel({
 name: req.body.name,
 value: req.body.value,
 title: req.body.title,
 content: req.body.content,
});
offer.save(function (err) {
 if (!err) {
    return console.log("created offer" + req.body.name);
  } else {
    return console.log(err);
  }
});
 return res.send(offer);
});
```

And here is the model:

```
var offerSchema = mongoose.Schema({

offer            : {
        name        : String,
        value       : String,
        title       : String,
        content     : String,
        image       : String,
        start       : String,
        end         : String,
        targets     : String,
        beacons     : String,
        published   : String
}
});
var OfferModel = mongoose.model('Offer', offerSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema is incorrect, must be like this:

```
var offerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name        : String,
    value       : String,
    title       : String,
    content     : String,
    image       : String,
    start       : String,
    end         : String,
    targets     : String,
    beacons     : String,
    published   : String
});
```